# python 3 class instances calling each others' attributes/variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my main module "actormain" looks like this:

```
import bodymain as bd
import soulmain as sl
(import statements of the other relevant modules, long and not super relevant)

class actor():
    def __init__(self, name, pron1, pron2, desc):
        self.name = name
        print ('creating ' + self.name + '.')
        self.owner = self
        self.pron1 = pron1
        self.pron2 = pron2
        self.desc = desc
        self.body = bd.body(self.owner)
        self.soul = sl.soul(self.owner)
        self.greet()



    def greet(self):
        print (self.pron1 + ' calls out, "Hey, my name\'s ' + self.name + '."')
```

it sets "self.body" to a value (which is an instance of another class, "body()," in another module) and then builds the rest of the body in increasing detail (for ex: body instance contains instances of "hands()" class, defined in a third module), passing along the actor instance as the variable "owner".

my problem: in the command line, i can reference, say,

`actor_instance.body.hands.owner.body.hands.fingers.owner.body... etc.` and it works fine. but if i try to reference that (with the same exact syntax!) from within the instance "fingers," for example, i get `"AttributeError: 'actor' object has no attribute 'body'."`

more, if in the command line, i say:

```
>>>a = actor(args)

>>>a.body.owner.body

<bodymain.body object at 0x0000000002F74A90>
```

so clearly the actor object has a body attribute.

but upon loading, this:

```
>>> import actormain as am
>>> b = am.actor('bob', 'he', 'his', 'slim')
creating bob.
incarnating bob.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#268>", line 1, in <module>
    b = am.actor('bob', 'he', 'his', 'slim')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python361\lib\actormain.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.body = bd.body(self.owner, self.bodydesc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python361\lib\bodymain.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.hand = so.hand(self.owner, '')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python361\lib\sensorg.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.fingers = fingers(self.owner, '')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python361\lib\sensorg.py", line 110, in __init__
    self.a = self.owner.body
AttributeError: 'actor' object has no attribute 'body'
```

what the hell is going on? why can't i reference this?

Comment: Please show a complete, self-contained example demonstrating what doesn't work.  Maybe `self.owner` isn't what you think it is in the `fingers` class.

Comment: from the command line, referencing fingers.owner gives the actor object, and fingers.owner.body gives the actor's body object.

Comment: . . . Please show a complete, self-contained example demonstrating what doesn't work.

Comment: and there it is. i hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the traceback what is happening.  Your code calls `self.body = body(...)` to create a body.  During the course of creating the body, some code tries to access the "owner's" body.  But the owner has no body yet, because it's still in the process of being created.

If your body parts need to be able to access the body, you can't create them from inside the body creation.  The body won't exist until the call to `body(...)` completely finishes and returns.